# yii2 dropdownlist options value and text php

Tags: php, yii2

`$list= ArrayHelper::map(contact::find()->all(), 'id', 'name');`

`echo $form->field($model, 'id')->dropDownList( $list,    array('onchange'=>"alert($(this).value);"));`

Eg.

`<option value="1">AAAA</option>
<option value="2">BBBB</option>
<option value="3">CCCC</option>`

In this case i am getting the value as 1 or 2 or 3.

How to get the text AAAAA or BBBB or CCCC on change?

Comment: `'onchange'=>'alert($("#'.Html::getInputId($model, 'id').' option:selected").text());'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @scaisEdge, with your input i found the solution.

`echo $form->field($model, 'id')->dropDownList( $list, 
     array('onchange'=>"alert($(this).find(':selected').text());"));`

Answer (score 1):

Yuo can use jquery val() ond option:selected

Could be

```
echo $form->field($model, 'id')->dropDownList( $list, 
     array('onchange'=>"alert( $( this + ' option:selected').val());"));
```

Comment: I tried it. its alerting all the options text. eg. AAAA,BBBBB,CCCCC